# hardware monitoring in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring

What are some suggested ways to monitor hardware status on Ubuntu machines? (i.e. check processor status, if a hard drive is conneccted, fan rpms, temperature) The goal is to make the monitoring as hardware independent as possible? For example, no reconfiguration if there is a supermico motherboard or gigabyte motherboad.

I've looked into solutions such as SBLIM, but the providers seem to be lacking. SNMP based solutions also look promising, but hard drive information has proven to be difficult.

Any suggestions, or solutions you use?hardware monitoring in Ubuntu

Comment: Should this be moved / asked on http://ServerFault.com/ or http://SuperUser.com/ ? Appears to not be programming related.

Answer (score 1):

You could run **gkrellmd** and use the client **gkrellm** to connect to remote computers and get statistics from the daemon.

Answer (score 0):

[munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/) is pretty easy to set up. You can just it locally, but it is usual to use a server to collect data from all the nodes

Answer (score 0):

[Nagios](http://nagios.org/) is a popular choice for monitoring systems used in industry. It might be a little excessive depending on your requirements but it IS extremely scalable and customizable (and can monitor windows machines too...)